# How to make Visio stencil opened by default

Tags: vba, visio, stencils

I try to make my macro available by default on any opened Visio drawing.
In Excel there is **Personal.xlsb**, but Visio...

I only found that way: saved that macro in the .vssm file, and now i need to open the .vssm in every document where i want my macro to work.

Is there is a way to open users .vssm by default in every document which Visio work with?

For now i found one *possible* solution: http://www.paulherber.co.uk/visio-utilities/.
They say *"Favourite (startup) stencils - always open these stencils when Visio starts"*. But may be there is another (free) way to do this?

I tryed to find Visio setting related to default stencils in registry and config files, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are right visio do not have default storage for macroses, which can be available for all documents ! In site where MS developers collect suggestions from users, which new functions and features they need get in MS Visio, you can find my suggestion
[Local storage for macros, which available for all documents](https://visio.uservoice.com/forums/368205-visio-for-developers/suggestions/16471033-local-storage-for-macros-which-available-for-all)
if more then 5 users voted for this suggestion, developers can start implement it

---

Six years ago in Russian Visio forum was thread [Where to write macros that are common to all open documents?](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?to=en&refd=www.translatoruser.net&r=true&a=http%3A%2F%2Fvisio.getbb.ru%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D6%26t%3D197%26st%3D0%26sk%3Dt%26sd%3Da%26start%3D80) (you can read this via [Microsoft Translator service](https://www.bing.com/translator))
In [that message](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fvisio.getbb.ru%2Fviewtopic.php%3Fp%3D1512%26sid%3Da9f5eeac469a58a521409fbd8af17c0c%23p1512) you can find add-in which works with Visio 2007 and Visio 2010!
As I know this add-in don't support and updated these years.